# OCR tesseract: trained data creation issue for special type of fonts (using Jtessboxeditor)

Tags: ocr, tesseract

- Unable to create proper trained data for windows non-native fonts, i.e.,for catia drafting fonts
- Even if some of the alpha-numerals are recognized, letters with broken characters like " i , j " etc.,  special symbols like Ø (Phi), ° (degree), ± (plus-minus) are not recognized properly. Its box file values are improper.
- JTessboxeditor is the tool we used to train and create trained data for tesseract

Request your assistance on the same. Thanks

Comment: Any earlier replies would be of greater help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also need these 3 characters - though it might be too late to answer this.

May not be of much help in all situations, but the Norwegian .traineddata file does include the Ø (Phi) character, this trained data file has helped me with this character.

The ° (degree) character may be a bit trickier, as it normally isn't recognized because it's too small, if you can see the inside of the character is clear, Tesseract might be able to decipher.

Now the most difficult, the ± (plus-minus). I haven't cracked this one yet, and this may be a very wooly approach; but I was thinking, the plus-minus is always recognized as + plus only.

I can use this to my advantage.

I could use Tesseract's engine which exposes **PageSegMode.SingleChar** to detect each individual character and use Tesseract's **GetSegmentedRegions()** to get the area of the bitmap/image where each character is - you can later reassemble all characters into a string.

Then I could run an ImageMagick to calculate/compare how similar the plus character found is to an image of either plus or plus-minus. The one with most similarity will tell you which character.

With my approach, I still have to parse the text recognised and transform it into something usable.
The Ø (Phi) character for example may be detected as lower-case, but I will want it upper-case.
Or the degree is detected as an apostrophe, but the expected result is the degree.
Another transformation is when I detect a dimension, a decimal may be incorrectly recognized with a comma, but I will want the decimal separator to be a dot (1,99 - 1.99)